# Gitlab - fatal: unable to access - Could not resolve host --> due missing slash

Tags: gitlab, trailing-slash

I have install new Gitlab instalation on my Ubuntu server with Apache2 websrver. I  created here (in web GUI) new repository like "testik.git" and I get http path:

> http://git.domain.tld/testovic/testik.git

But, when I put this in git command on my winPC

```
git clone http://git.domain.tld/testovic/testik.git
```

Command return

```
Cloning into 'testik'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.domain.tld/testovic/testik.git/': Could not resolve host: git.domain.tldtestovic
```

I see **unnecessary trailing slash** in "fatal" information and I see too, that this **slash is missing after "TLD"** before "username".

And same problem is, when I open project in webGUI and click on leftside menu e.g. to "Security&Compliance" --> "Configuration" and in e.g. first part named "Static Application Securty Testing (SAST)" try to click on button "Configure with a merge request".

I have got error page with URL starting with
https://git.domain.tldtestovic/testik/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request....

I see here missing slash after TLD again ... when I put manually slash after TLD and press enter, everything is fully funtional.

Do you have somebody any good idea, any solution what to do with missing slash after TLD ? Where could be the problem?

I know, that this is not problem of DNS, because ping git.domain.tld is OK. I suppose, that something wrong need to be in configuration.

In **\etc\gitlab\gitlab.rh** I have done these manuall changes

```
external_url 'http://git.domain.tld'
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['<my Ubuntu serverIP>']
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = "<some good password>"
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
gitlab_rails['db_encodig'] = "unicode"
gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "<database name>"
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "<some username>"
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = "<some another good password>"
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = "<correct address to the nonlocalhost DB server>"
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
gitlab_workhouse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhouse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
postgresql['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

I read a lot of post, pages, etc. But without success. Thank you very much for the way to functional git with Gitlab.